# SQL Server Pivot Table, Null Results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

This is a popular question I know. I am just learning about pivot tables and don't know where I am going wrong.

```
create table #test
(
     id varchar(4), 
     code varchar(2), 
     received_dt varchar(8)
)

insert into #test values ('1234','10','20150312')
insert into #test values ('1234','71','20150312')
insert into #test values ('1234','C5','20150312')
insert into #test values ('4321','10','20150312')
insert into #test values ('4321','71','20150312')
insert into #test values ('987','10','20150312')
insert into #test values ('987','71','20150312')
insert into #test values ('987','C5','20150312')

select id, [code1], [code2], [code3]
from #test
pivot(MAX(code) for code in ([code1], [code2], [code3])) as pvt

drop table #test
```

Any help/guidance is greatly appreciated. I know this should be easy but I can't seem to wrap my brain around it.

Results in:

```
ID      Code1   Code2   Code3
1234    NULL    NULL    NULL
4321    NULL    NULL    NULL
987     NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Want:

```
ID      Code1   Code2   Code3
1234    10      71      C5
4321    10      71      NULL
987     10      71      C5
```

**EDIT** There are MANY code values.

Comment: you should really post the result that you want to get

Comment: thanks realized only after I posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to create another column that contains the `Code1, Code2, Code3` values:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *, 
            RN = 'Code' + 
                 CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY code) AS CHAR(1))
    FROM #test
)
SELECT id, [code1], [code2], [code3]
FROM CTE
PIVOT(MAX(code) for RN in ([code1], [code2], [code3])) as pvt;
```

**UPDATE**

If you have an unknown number of codes, you'll need dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'', @cols NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *, 
            RN = 'Code' + 
                 CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY code) AS CHAR(1))
    FROM #test
)
SELECT @cols += STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(RN)
                       FROM CTE
                       GROUP BY RN
                       FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '');


SET @sql = N'
SELECT *
FROM (  SELECT  *,
                RN = ''Code'' + 
                 CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY code) AS CHAR(1))
    FROM #test) AS d
PIVOT(MAX(code) for RN in (' + @cols + ')) AS p;';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: The dynamic part is what did the trick for me. Thank you so much!